# CSS Overflow: Force one div to overflow

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to let only a certain element overflow a parent div?

I'm hiding all the child divs from overflowing, but I need one of the children elements to overflow and float outside the limiting parent.

See http://sandbox.pixelcraftwebdesign.com/engineering and run some calculations with random numbers.

The little red number in the upper right-hand corner needs to float over and outside the output div.

Comment: I would suppose jQuery could help. Please post some code.

Comment: +1 some code would help.

Comment: That page is running in quirks mode.  Put it in standards mode to get consistent results across browsers.

Comment: If you want that little red box to completely be out of the output box, just remove the position:relative; from the output div and the box should float right out. But since it's running quirks like @gilly3 said, it may or may not work for you. It worked for me using chrome's inspection tool.

Comment: Your `doctype` controls your rendering mode (quirks or standards).  Yours specifies HTML3.2, which puts your document in quirks mode.  There are numerous ways of coding your doctype.  Here's a decent article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/.  But, my preference is to keep it short and sweet.  This concise syntax will keep your document in standards mode: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: How does it look now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the widths to remain the same:

1. Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.output`.
2. Set `.output .right` to `width:257px;overflow:hidden`.
3. Set `.result-rh, .result-temp` to `width:241px`.

This fix allows overflow on the container, but hides overflow on the right side. It also gives the right side the appropriate size, to prevent the result SPANs from being clipped.

Works for me in Firefox 3.6.17. Should work in other browsers as well.

Comment: Good fix. I'm embarrassed that I didn't see this first... :)

Answer (score 5):

not entirely sure what you are after, but here is a fiddle demonstrating a certain child div floating outside and displaying all of its contents: http://jsfiddle.net/dcpDa/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="doShow">Okay, Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
    <div class="dontShow">Dont Show All Of Me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { 
    width: 5em; /*constrain div */
    height: 1em; 
    border: 1px solid #aaa; 
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.dontShow { overflow: hidden; } /* do not show overflow */

.doShow { 
    width: auto; /* over ride constraints and show all */
    height: auto;  
    position: absolute; /* break from flow */ 
    left: 15em; /* position where you want */
}
```

Here are two articles on CSS positioning I  found usefull recently:
[css Floats 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)
[Css Positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

Answer (score 3):

If the element you want to overflow is text, the simpliest solution is :

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Flyout/dgh2erqj/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` on the child you want to show.  You can then use `top`, `left`, `height`, and `width` to position it where you want.

Comment: The child element will not be visible if the parent is set to `overflow:hidden` and you position it outside.